# Consecutive Animations - Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm looking to have a variety of animations for an apple watch app.  I'm using a series of images and the method of animation is startAnimatingWithImagesInRange().  Any time I have consecutive animation instructions, only the last one in the code executes.  Code looks like:

```
myImage.setImageNamed("testImage")

myImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 90), duration: 3, repeatCount: 1)

myImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location: 90, length: 180), duration: 3, repeatCount: 1)
```

In the above code, only the second animation would play.  I even tried putting them in separate functions, so I would be calling each function individually, but it still will only play the last animation in my code.  I'm fairly new to this so I'm sure there is a better way but after hours and hours of research I haven't been able to come up with a solution or find one online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The watch won't queue up animations for you, so use an NSTimer with a delay equal to the duration of the first animation and start the second animation once the timer fires.

Comment: I had thought about that as an option but I figured there had to be a better way.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: really there is no other way other than to use a NStimer to know when the animation ended? That doesn't seem right. There is a method called animationDidStop:<#(CAAnimation *)#> finished:<#(BOOL)#>] on WKInterfaceImage

Comment: I don't see the animationDidStop:finished: message on the public API for WKInterfaceImage.  Are you seeing it by iterating the object methods directly?

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper guys.  For what its worth, I'm also not using a WKInterfaceImage.  I'm actually using a group that acts as a button and updating the group's background image through the group's IBOutlet.  Also, I can't find the animationDidStop in watch kit anywhere either.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy as 1 + 1 :)

Here is what you want:

```
myImage.setImageNamed("testImage")

let duration = 3
let repeatCount = 1

Timeline.with(identifier: "MyQueuedAnimation", delay: 0.0, duration: duration * repeatCount, execution: {

    myImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 90), duration: duration, repeatCount: repeatCount)

}, completion: {

    myImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location: 90, length: 180), duration: duration, repeatCount: 1)

}).start
```

[TimelineKit](https://github.com/DevAndArtist/TimelineKit) - feel free to give me some feedback for my little framework. :)

Comment: There is still the issue that when the images are loaded for the first time after foregrounding the app, the animation takes slightly longer to play (the system somehow preloads them so that the animation is not choppy).

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my little framework? Feel free to file an issue on Github, and I'll take a look. ;)

Comment: no, your framework is nice, but the problem is in the WatchKit - you cannot precisely tell when your animation will finish animating (it may take longer than the duration parameter), so there is currently no way to guarantee that completion block will be called when the animation is really finished.